# Java servlet response to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a Java Servlet to send some HTML as a response to a request from a JavaScript function. However, while the servlet function is getting called and seems to be sending a response, the Javascript functions is getting nothing but an empty String.

Here is the Servlet method:

```
String type = request.getParameter("type");
if(type.equals("locos")) {
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            //this prints out
            System.out.println("Responding with vehicle list");

            //deal with response
             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
             out.write("<p>test response</p>"); //finish
        }
```

Here is the JavaScript function:

```
this.updateVehicleList = function () {
        var type = "locos";

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'GetList?type=' + encodeURIComponent(type),true);
        xhr.send(null);

        //deal with response
        var res = xhr.responseText;

        //for testing
        if (res == "") {
            window.alert("I'm getting nothing");
        }

        view.showVehicleList(res);
    };
```

The "I'm getting nothing" message outputs every time. How do I get the JavaScript to actually receive the response from the Servlet?

Comment: Related: [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an asynchronous request and so the response is not immediately available. You are trying to get the `responseText` before the response has even been received.

Use the `onreadystatechange` event:

```
...
...
xhr.send(null);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200){
        //deal with response
        var res = xhr.responseText;

         //for testing
         if (res == "") {
            window.alert("I'm getting nothing");
         }

        view.showVehicleList(res);
    }
};
```

If you are intending to make a synchronous request, then set the third argument to `false` and your original code will work.

```
xhr.open('GET', 'GetList?type=' + encodeURIComponent(type),false);
//                                                         ^^^^^
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks.